# To Make File name according to their IDs

Tags: awk, files, grep, rename

I want to replace each file name with their specific IDs. My files are 30,000 and so their respective IDs. Can it be possible to fetch ID which is inside in each file on line number 2 and become a name of that file?

Comment: instead of attaching file, can you put the contents here..

Comment: thank you for asking. but now it's done

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/

Comment: @JdeBP ok I will be conscious next time

Answer (score 1):

Try to use loop, ex. for.

```
for f in *; do nn=`sed -n 2p $f`; mv $f $nn; done
```

- `*` — get list of files
- `nn=…` — catch the 2nd line from file (get new
  name)
- `mv …` — rename file